# Starting a EJB dependency in CDI project

Tags: ejb, cdi

Well, i need use @Schedule (EJB) to put a task in crontab. I know that CDI dont have this (unhappy), just EJB. All my beans are CDI-Managed, so i have some doubts to include EJB inside this project, i hope that you can help me:

1) I'll create a new bean to use @Schedule, but i dont know if this bean should use @Singleton (EJB) or @Named + @RequestScoped (CDI). My ideia is that:

```
@Singleton
public class RoboFtp implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private VideoBOImpl videoBO;

    @Schedule(...)
    public void coletarVideo(){
        //do something each 3 seconds
    }

}
```

Note that i have a CDI Bean inside a EJB Bean, this is possible ? This above bean is correct ?

2) How can i add the ejb to my pom.xml ?

3) If i add EJB to my project can have any conflicts ? Because my project is already in production.

Comment: Can you give me some example how to do it only with CDI ?

Comment: You can create scheduled Executors with JDK 8.  What's the problem?

Comment: I know how to inject the bean with Spring.  Not sure how to do the same with CDI, but I'll bet it's similar.

Comment: I didn't use Spring.

Comment: I know that, but dependency injection in Java EE was practically written by Rod Johnson.  I'm sure the annotations are similar.  Create one of these and inject it as you know how: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

Comment: can you give me example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dispel your worries:

> 1) CDI Bean inside a EJB Bean, this is possible ?

CDI && EJB works pretty well together. In fact CDI will detect EJB beans and turn them into CDI beans as well. So if you create, say `@Stateful` bean, it will be picked up as CDI bean as well. That means you will be able to perform any CDI-related magic there while still having EJB features.

As for choice of annotation, `@Singleton` sounds reasonable; or probably `@Stateful`?. `@RequestScoped` would only live during request and die afterwards hence killing your periodic task. Choose scope based on nature of your task (one bean vs many/ short lived vs permanent/ ..). Just make sure you **make it an EJB bean** and CDI will follow.

> 2) How can i add the ejb to my pom.xml ?

Assuming you have Maven project, add a dependency on EJB api, the implementation will be provided by your Java EE application server.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
  <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
  <version>${desiredVersion}</version>
</dependency>
```

> 3)  If i add EJB to my project can have any conflicts ?

Too general question I am afraid; I do not know your project. But I'll go ahead and say "no". At least as far as CDI and EJB goes, you should be able to deal with it.

Comment: Very helpful informations, but a last question : Do i need a Application Server (Jboss, Glassfish, TomEE) to run EJB ? Can i run in tomcat7 ?

Comment: Tomcat in a servlet and as such is not required to support EJB. You will need a proper server. The easiest way to adopt one (assuming you have Tomcat now) is probably TomEE. 

By the way, if you find this information sufficient, please mark my answer as a solution.